# Set hover area to close subnav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set the mouseout area of the screen either between the main (red) links at the top, or outside of the subnav (green), so that when a user moves the mouse outside of the main nav, the subnav will close?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

var d = document;
var navSub = d.querySelector('.nav-sub');
var navHeader = d.querySelector('.nav-header');

function toggleDrawer(state){
  navHeader.dataset.drawerDisplay = state;
}

//ADDING THIS TOGGLE STATE ALLOWS THE USER TO CLOSE THE SUBNAV BY CLICKING IT, BUT DISABLES HOVER (NOW REQUIRES CLICKING) OF MAIN NAV TO OPEN SUBNAV. ALSO MESSING WITH MOBILE NAVIGATION.
$(".nav-header").on('click',function(){
      $(".nav-sub").slideToggle("hide");
    });

// Header nav drawer
function toggleNav(){
  var opener = d.querySelectorAll('.opener');
  [].forEach.call(opener, function(el, index) {
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
        toggleDrawer('show');
        navHeader.dataset.drawerNum = index;
      });

      el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        navSub.addEventListener('mouseenter', showDrawer('show'));
        navSub.addEventListener('mouseout', toggleDrawer('hide'));
        toggleDrawer('hide');
        navHeader.dataset.drawerNum = "";
      });
  });
}
toggleNav();
```

[image]

Comment: What should happen if the mouse is between the red and green area?

Comment: If one of the subnavs are visible because the user has hovered over one of the main nav items, the subnav should remain visible until the user has hovered over another main nav item, or moved outside of the main nav (far left or far right)

Comment: Basically, I need to have the subnav close when the user either mouses out of the main navigation area to the left or right, or moves the mouse outside of the subnav (green area). The subnav currently just stays visible until the user moves to the next main nav link or moves the mouse to the search icon.

Comment: @user3438917 try adding in your li,ul and 'red box container' height:100%

Comment: @QoP - the markup doesn't use list elements. Also, why would I set the height of the main nav to 100%?